# Does UE4/5 Leverage GPU for Video Rendering?

Tags: rendering, render, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to generate many hours of video of a 3D board game. I have a powerful RTX 3090, and I want to utilize it as much as possible.

Can UE4/5 effectively leverage GPU resources to render video? If not, is there a better engine to effectively leverage GPUs for rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnrealEngine provides a very advanced cinematic tools,including movie render queue module which allows rendering the UE view-port to image sequence or video (very limited number of formats). However, UE doesn't encode video on GPU in that specific case. I write "that specific" for a reason. UE does use Nvidia GPU encoder(if available) for fast and efficient encoding to H264 when Pixel Streamer feature is used to stream video with WebRTC. But this one is for interactive streaming of the engine,not for video encoding. So even though you can deploy UE in a remote render farm and try to encode a massive amount of video data, it won't be as fast as using dedicated hardware encoder, such as NVIDIA NVENC. Moreover, UE doesn't provide video encoding to H264 at all. You would have to encode into JPG/PNG/BMP image sequence,then use tool like FFMPEG to convert to video. I recently put on GitHub an [MP4 encoder plugin](https://github.com/sasmaster/MP4ExporterUE4) for UnrealEngine, which I wrote for my needs, but this one uses also CPU to perform encoding.